# jQuery switch active class depending on which section is showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several sections within a document as follows:

```
<section id="step1">
</section>

<section id="step2" style="display:none">
</section>

<section id="step3" style="display:none">
</section>
```

I am showing and hiding these depending on user interaction. I wanted to have some kind of circular heading to indicate the user is on section 2 of 3 for example like so:

```
        <div id="indicators" class="clearfix">
        <div class="center-div">
            <ul>
                <li id="step1-circle" class="circle active"></li>
                <li id="step2-circle" class="circle"></li>
                <li id="step3-circle" class="circle"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How would I switch the active class depending on which section is showing?

Comment: is the toggling of a section triggered by an event like a click? or does it only do that on pageload?

Comment: You should provide more code, you can target the active class of the showing section simply by `$('section:visible .circle.active')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `addClass()` method in tandem with the `removeClass()` method like:

```
function makeIndicatorCircleActive(id){

   // Remove active state of current circle
   $('#indicators .active').removeClass('active');

   // Add active state to desired element
   $(id).addClass('active');

}

// Somewhere else in the code...
makeIndicatorCircleActive('#step2-circle);
```

Comment: Also worth taking a look at [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: The only reason why I'm not a fan of `toggleClass()` is because it is not explicit in the code of what action it is performing, where `addClass()` and `removeClass()` are easily readable in knowing what change will be taking place

Answer (score 0):

I've added a button for the animation.  You'd need to show more example code of your implementation, but you may be able to get away with `let $section = $('section:visible')` and instead of putting this in a click function, create a generic function name, which is triggered whenever your event occurs.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  // context used for jQuery
  let $section = $(this).closest('section');

  // get next circle, if current circle is last, then get first circle
  var $next = $('.circle.active', $section).next('.circle'),
    $next = ($next.length && $next) || $('.circle', $section).first();

  $('.circle.active', $section).removeClass('active'); // remove all actives
  $next.addClass('active'); // add new active
});
```

```css
.circle {
  background:            black;
  border-radius:         25px;
  display:               inline-block;
  list-style-type:       none;
  width:                 50px;
  height:                50px;
  -moz-border-radius:    25px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="center-div">
      <ul>
        <li class="circle active"></li>
        <li class="circle"></li>
        <li class="circle"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
  <div class="clearfix">
    <div class="center-div">
      <ul>
        <li class="circle active"></li>
        <li class="circle"></li>
        <li class="circle"></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <button>Next</button>
  </div>
</section>
```